# How to Test and Run a Client Server Program in C++ using Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, server, udp, client-server

I am trying to get started with UDP and would like to test and debug some client server programs.

I am using an Eclipse IDE with cygwin64 as a compiler.

I have found some example client server programs from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/

I would like to be able to run the example to get me started on learning about UDP client servers.

The example code is as follows:

**Server**

```
    // Server side implementation of UDP client-server model
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT     8080
#define MAXLINE 1024

// Driver code
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    char *hello = "Hello from server";
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));

    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family    = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the socket with the server address
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    int len, n;
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
                &len);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Client : %s\n", buffer);
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello),
        0, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
            len);
    printf("Hello message sent.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Client**

```
// Client side implementation of UDP client-server model 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 

#define PORT     8080 
#define MAXLINE 1024 

// Driver code 
int main() { 
    int sockfd; 
    char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
    struct sockaddr_in     servaddr; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    int n, len; 

    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello), 
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,  
            sizeof(servaddr)); 
    printf("Hello message sent.\n"); 

    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,  
                MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
                &len); 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer); 

    close(sockfd); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I have tried opening up two different eclipse workbenches and running both the codes, but it is not running as expected and it is saying that the messages have been sent but I have not been able to receive them on the client or server.

I definitely would like to stick with c/c++ and try to get this working in eclipse if it's possible.

If anyone has any advice on how I can be able to see some results or anything that could get me started with this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated: I haven't seen `MSG_WAITALL` implemented for UDP because it's packet oriented. You either get a packet or you don't. If you don't read the whole packet, buffer is too small, that's your problem. If your message exceeds the maximum size of a packet, the message will be fragmented and it's up to you to clean up the mess if packets are lost or delivered out of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

You have not set the address of the server correctly in the client code.

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

is meaningless when sending (Why would you want to send to any available address? You want to send to the server.) and is rejected by `sendto`. You would have seen this if you'd checked the return value. Always check the return value, even for UDP communications. Sure there are a million reasons why a packet won't arrive with UDP that you can't detect at the time of `sendto`, but it's good to know that the network stack actually accepted the message even if a [grue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grue_(monster)) subsequently devours the packet in one of the dark corners of the Internet. A sending error you can do something about, like `perror` and then fix the code accordingly. A grue, not so much. You'll have to make a protocol robust enough to retransmit or otherwise survive the loss of the packet.

## Solution

Get the server's address structure with `getaddrinfo`.

Replace

```
// Filling server information 
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

with something more like

```
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *hostlist;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = 0;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP; 

if (getaddrinfo("Server Name or Address Goes Here",
                PORT, // this needs to be a char *, not an integer
                &hints,
                &hostlist))
{
    // handle error
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

`PORT` in this case needs to be a `char *`, so instead of

```
#define PORT     8080
```

use

```
constexpr char const * PORT = "8080";
```

You can leave out the `constexpr` if your compiler is old and doesn't support it.

Then when you go to send, iterate through the `hostlist` until you find a host that responds. Since you've probably narrowed the servers down to exactly one candidate, this is probably overkill, but you might as well get into practice doing things right. The alternative sucks when systems start getting complicated.

```
struct addrinfo *curhost;
for (curhost = hostlist; curhost != NULL; curhost = curhost->ai_next)
{
    int rval = sendto(sockfd,
                      (const char *) hello,
                      strlen(hello),
                      0,
                      curhost->ai_addr,
                      curhost->ai_addrlen);
    if (rval> 0) // always check return codes. Programmers are lazy. 
                 // They wouldn't have gone to the effort of putting
                 // it there if it wasn't important.
    {
        if server responds
            do protocol stuff to complete transaction
            break;
    }
}
freeaddrinfo(hostlist); // thou shalt not leak resources.
if (curhost == nullptr)
{
    notify user that no server was willing to talk
}
```

[Documentation for `getaddrinfo`.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)

Comment: Good response on all levels.  To answer the OPs original question: "Yes, two instances of Eclipse in separate workbenches is a good way to run both programs at the same time."  @Darklink9110 - fix the coding errors user4581301 pointed out, and you should be good to go.  ALSO: Check out [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)